# Determine offending file when running Apache's configtest

Tags: apache-2.2

Is there a way to determine the offending file when running `https configtest`.

For example, instead of:

```
Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/whatever.com/webroot] does not exist
Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/example.com/webroot] does not exist
```

I could see:

```
Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/whatever.com/webroot] does not exist in /etc/httpd/conf.d/file.conf
Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/example.com/webroot] does not exist in /etc/httpd/conf.d/other_file.conf
```

I reviewed help/man and searched, but could not find an option or equivalent command.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, apachectl does not offer this information.

Your best solution is to simply use `grep` to search the config files for the string shown in the error message.

Comment: + Although, lame. Not ideal when conf files are spread across different directories. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure the apache project would appreciate a patch that would give the extra information.

Comment: Agreed. Wish I had the skills/time write it.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a little of extra info, the `apachectl` script doesn't do much on its own, just invokes the `httpd` binary with a flag:

```
 configtest)
    $HTTPD -t
    ERROR=$?
    ;;
```

So this has to be addressed in the core itself.

This is fixed in `apache-2.4`:

```
# systemctl status httpd
httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2014-06-20 20:36:01 CEST; 1s ago
  Process: 3331 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3329 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 3329 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Total requests: 0; Current requests/sec: 0; Current traffic:   0 B/sec"

Jun 20 20:36:01 foo.com httpd[3329]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 15 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/012-some-vhost.conf:
Jun 20 20:36:01 foo.com httpd[3329]: Invalid command 'UseCanonicalNamex', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Jun 20 20:36:01 foo.com systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 20 20:36:01 foo.com systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Jun 20 20:36:01 foo.com systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
```

The relevant code is in `server/config.c`.

Comment: So no need for me to learn C and update core :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/set-up-virtual-hosts-in-apache-on-macos-high-sierra-10-13/) tutorial check `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`. This worked on my machine which is OSX 10.13 using Apache 2.4.